# Foreach only runs once

Tags: mysql, foreach

I am modifying a procedure in MYSQL to accept a delimited list. The list will be numbers separated by commas:

> 793, 654, 803...

I have a section in my procedure to test the Destinations variable which holds the list and uses a foreach:

```
CALL FOREACH(Destinations, 'INSERT INTO destination (uid, destId,
subscription_start, subscription_end, valid) VALUES (UsrID, $(1),
NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 31 day, 1)');
```

When I call the code and pass in those three examples above (793, 654, 803), I notice it only runs the statement once on the first number. One row gets inserted instead of all 3 like I wanted. It only ever returns the first row in the list.

How can I get this to process once for each item I am passing in? [Here](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-foreach) is what I was using for my reference.

Comment: How is Destinations populated?

Comment: Yeah, if you're getting the values for Destinations by fetching from a SELECT, then just fetch the values one row at a time and in a loop run your own INSERT statement. IMHO, the foreach procedure is a bad idea. Too much magic, too hard to debug. It seems the docs for common-schema are broken (perhaps because of google code shutdown?).

Comment: But the answer to your question is that the foreach procedure is obviously not parsing your list of numbers correctly. The blog says the list should be space-separated, but the example shows a list that is space-and-comma-separated. Since the docs are offline, you may have to read the code to understand how it truly parses. Or contact the author.